# EF Core create transaction log table

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Since EF Core 7, it's not allowed to have triggers on tables.

I have a problem with these entities:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; } = new List<OrderDetail>();
}

public class OrderDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }

    public List<OrderDetailTransaction> OrderDetailTransactions { get; set; } = new List<OrderDetailTransaction>();

    public Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetailTransaction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }

    public OrderDetail OrderDetail { get; set; }
}
```

When an `Order` is added & I call `SaveChanges`, I expect the `OrderDetail.OrderId` & `OrderDetailTransaction.OrderDetailId` to get the new identity numbers, but I find it only on `OrderDetail.OrderId` - `OrderDetailTransaction.OrderId` is still zero.

Can I know how to do it in modelbuilder ?

Answer (score 0):

When specified as "foreign key", The foreign keys should auto get new identity numbers.
You could try following to specify the "primary key" and "foreign key".
Order.cs

```
    public class Order
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; } = new List<OrderDetail>();
    }
```

OrderDetail.cs

```
    public class OrderDetail
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public List<OrderDetailTransaction> OrderDetailTransactions { get; set; } = new List<OrderDetailTransaction>();


        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
        public Order Order { get; set; }
    }
```

OrderDetailTransaction.cs

```
    public class OrderDetailTransaction
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }

        public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("OrderDetailId")]
        public OrderDetail OrderDetail { get; set; }
    }
```

(Note that there shouldn't be an `public int OrderId { get; set; }` in class OrderDetailTransaction. Even if you add it, it cannot be configured as a foreignkey, because you already have nested one-to-many relationship.)
MyContext.cs

```
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySql("server=192.168.2.68;database=WA72;user=mysql1;password=xxxxxx", new MySqlServerVersion(new Version()));
        }

        public DbSet<Order> OrderTable { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetailTable { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderDetailTransaction> OrderDetailTransactioTable { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .HasMany(a => a.OrderDetails)
                .WithOne(b => b.Order);

            modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetail>()
                .HasMany(a => a.OrderDetailTransactions)
                .WithOne(b => b.OrderDetail);      
        }
    }
```

Test controller

```
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public void test()
        {
            var order = new Order
            {
                OrderNumber = "A01",
                OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>
                {
                    new OrderDetail
                    {
                        Color="red",
                        OrderDetailTransactions= new List<OrderDetailTransaction>
                        {
                            new OrderDetailTransaction{Color="blue"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            _context.OrderTable.Add(order);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

After execute:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, because I would like copy all saved OrderDetail rows into OrderDetailTransaction so when orderdetail have saved, there rows need to make whole copy to OrderDetailTransaction inside